# What's the best way to handle pointer & non-pointer template types in a custom std::vector-like container?

Tags: c++, templates, memory, memory-management, stl

So I'm building my own dynamic array container similar to std::vector for fun/research.  A stripped down header for my container looks like this:

```
template<class ElementClass> 
class Array
{
public:
    Array(class Allocator* allocator, size_t initialCapacity);
    ~Array();

    ...

private:
    class Allocator* allocator;
    ElementClass* pFirst;
    size_t m_capacity;
    size_t m_size;
};
```

So far my Array class is working nicely with any type I provide to the template (woohoo!).  However, my current implementation seems to choke hard when I try to use a pointer instead of an object type.  A good example of this would be in the destructor:

```
template<class ElementClass>
Array<ElementClass>::~Array()
{
    for (size_t c = 0; c < m_capacity; c++)
    {
        pFirst[c]->~ElementClass();
    }
    allocator->free(pFirst);
}
```

This obviously results in a nasty error, because if I were to make an `Array<int*>` for example, then `ElementClass` translates to `int*`, which the compiler rightfully trips on and proceeds to fall down a long set of stairs.  Also there are a few other places where this sort of thing happens, but I left those out for brevity.

So my question is: what is the correct way to handle this template class such that it allows me to create a template container that can handle pointers as well as non-pointer types?  Am I supposed to use some kind of template specialization technique for the functions where this sort of issue arises?   Thanks in advance.  :)

Comment: Instead of the clever metaphor, I suggest you cite the actual compiler errors. I don't see anything immediately wrong with this code. `pFirst[c]->~ElementClass()` should work just as well (namely, do nothing) when `ElementClass` is `int*` as when `ElementClass` is, say, `int`.

Comment: Are you sure you want that loop running up to `m_capacity`, and not `m_size`? In a typical implementation, elements between `m_size` and `m_capacity` would be uninitialized random garbage, reserved space to be filled later.

Comment: Try making a [mcve]. It's easier to help you if we don't have to guess what's going on.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The error, in my example of Array<int*> is "error C2325: 'int *': unexpected type to the right of '->~': expected 'int'".  And yes, running up to m_capacity is probably a bug, but that would be a run-time error, not compile-time as with my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you appear to be doing is calling the dtor on the element pointed to by the pointer, rather than the pointer values stored in the array. If your array is doing anything other than this in the dtor, it's doing it wrong....

```cpp
template<class ElementClass>
Array<ElementClass>::~Array()
{
    for (size_t c = 0; c < m_size; c++)
    {
        pFirst[c].~ElementClass();
    }
    allocator->free(pFirst);
}
```

To call the dtor on the objects pointed to by the pointers in the array seems highly dangerous to me. Who knows where those pointers have come from (NULL, stack allocated variables, etc).

> Array is "error C2325: 'int *': unexpected type to the right of '->~': expected 'int'".

ElementClass is of type **`int*`**. You are attempting to dereference that pointer, so now the type is **`int`**. You then are attempting to call the dtor for type **`int*`** on an **`int`**.

Comment: Oh god, woops!  You're right it should not have been "->~", it should really just be a ".~".  I think that fixed all my issues (along with fixing the m_size range).  Thank you for lending me your eyeballs.